# Why do fairies' lives not matter?

Tags: plot-explanation, bright

In *Bright* we see attempts at inter-species equality, e.g. giving proper chances to orcs by giving one a job in the LAPD. But why does no one seem to care about fairies? Why they are treated like pests?

From the film scene:

> **Neighbor:** Yo, that Fairy been all up in my crib, eating up my dog food and shit. I'm about to call the city, man.
>
> **Daryl Ward:** I *am* the city. All right? You save your dime. Fairy lives don't matter today.

Why it's so ok to treat fairies like this?

Comment: I don't remember seeing any other fairies in the movie. So from what I can speculate, they aren't "evolved", meaning, it's like killing a mosquito (because they are attracted to light). So I'm guessing it's somewhere, you put your judgement on this: will you kill an annoying mosquito? will you kill an annoying raccoon (for the "eating my dog food" similarity)? a homeless guy? Where would you consider the fairy in this?

Comment: Because they are a nuisance - just like mice, rats, deer and other common pests - and not capable of defending themselves very well. Despite their small but human-like appearance, they also don't appear to have evolved to the point of having language, so they can't complain very well.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it also seems like a reference (Diametrically Opposed) to the fairies (and mythos?) in Peter Pan. Is there any plot of subtext about growing up/coming of age or right of passage?? Granted sometimes fairies in lit or mythology are associated with demons, goblins, demoted angels, or gnomes. I haven't seen Bright yet to tell what allegories they might be playing on.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing a fairy to a homeless guy is a bad analogy, but... fairies are clearly not beneficial in the social context of this movie. The opening dialogue focuses on a discussion between Daryl and Sherri Ward (Will Smith/Dawn Olivieri) about calling a pest exterminator to deal with the fairy (outside their home). Following the fairy "extermination", you don't see another fairy again until one does a camera flyby immediately before the credits roll.
Why don't fairy lives matter?
Because they do not have a positive influence on their community. In fact, since the movie indicates that fairies eat dog food and create other issues, they actually create problems.